# I'm getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not execute method of activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an application in which I store some data in sqlite database. And on click of a button, retrieve the data from the database and try to store it in a table format.
This was working properly when I tried to store all the data in a textview, though not in a table format. Now, whenever I try to store the data in a table format using table layout, I'm  getting  runtime exception titled "java.lang.illegalStateException: Could not execute method of activity". Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**below is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView[] columsView;
     SQLiteDatabase db;
    //  TextView tv;
      EditText et1,et2;
      int k=0;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //initialize all view objects
      // tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
       columsView=new TextView[30];
       //create database if not already exist
       db= openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       //create new table if not already exist
       db.execSQL("create table if not exists mytable(name varchar, sur_name varchar)");
       }
       //This method will call on when we click on insert button
       public void insert(View v)
       {
        String name=et1.getText().toString();
        String sur_name=et2.getText().toString();
        et1.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
        //insert data into able
        db.execSQL("insert into mytable values('"+name+"','"+sur_name+"')");
       //display Toast
       Toast.makeText(this, "values inserted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       //This method will call when we click on display button
       public void display(View v)
       {
       //use cursor to keep all data
       //cursor can keep data of any data type
       Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from mytable", null);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      // tv.setText("");
       //move cursor to first position
       c.moveToFirst();
       //fetch all data one by one
       do
       {
        //we can use c.getString(0) here
        //or we can get data using column index
        String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String surname=c.getString(1);
        //display on text view
      //  sb.append(name).append(";").append(surname).append("_");
      /*  if(name==et1.getText().toString() && surname==et2.getText().toString())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
        //tv.append("Name:"+name+" and SurName:"+surname+"\n");
        //move next position until end of the data
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab); 
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        final String row=name+";"+surname;
        final String[] cols = row.split(";");
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {        
            final String col = cols[j];    

             columsView[k] = new TextView(this);  
            columsView[k].setText(String.format("%7s", col));                              
            tableRow.addView(columsView[k]);
            k++;
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        }


       }while(c.moveToNext());

       }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
public void forgot(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside forgot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent i=new Intent(this,ForgotPass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //moveTaskToBack(true);
            }

public void changepass(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside forgot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent i=new Intent(this,ChangePass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onBackPressed();
    db.close();
}
}
```

**This is my xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
   android:hint="Sur Name"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:ems="10" />
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
   android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
   android:text="Insert Values"
   android:onClick="insert"/>
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/button2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
   android:onClick="display"
   android:text="Display all Values" />


<Button
   android:id="@+id/button3"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
   android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
   android:onClick="forgot"
   android:text="forgot password" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/button4"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
   android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
   android:onClick="changepass"
   android:text="Change password" />

<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/button4" >

 <!--  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
  </LinearLayout> -->

       <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
     android:id="@+id/tab"       
    >

    </TableLayout>

 </ScrollView>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:maxLines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**below is the error i get:**

```
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     ... 11 more
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:421)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:403)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:394)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     at com.example.datbase.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:89)
08-12 10:59:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(4105):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: complete stack trace plz !!

Comment: To not edit the question in a way that would make existing answers invalid. The original problem is solved; to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

You're adding the same `TableRow` over and over again in your `for` loop in `display()`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {        
    // ...
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
```

Either add it outside the loop, or in case you want multiple rows, create a new `TableRow` for each iteration.

Comment: i'm new to android. could you please edit the display() function and post it. and, how to create a new TableRow for each iteration. should i use TableRow array?

Comment: Sir,i added it outside the loop. still not working. getting runtime error caused by "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on row 75.

Comment: final String col = cols[j]; is row no. 75. i can't find out the error

Answer (score 0):

Error on

```
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

The specified child (tableRow) has already parent.

You will need to create new TableRow each time in a loop as this:

```
    final String row=name+";"+surname;
    final String[] cols = row.split(";");
    for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {        
        final String col = cols[j]; 
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

        columsView[k] = new TextView(this);  
        columsView[k].setText(String.format("%7s", col));                              
        tableRow.addView(columsView[k]);
        k++;
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
```

This way, you will be able to add new table row to table layout. Hope it helps.

Edit:

You are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound for cols[2] as it has just 2 elements, cols[0] and cols[1].

Change

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still same error? or new? post logcat and updated code in question. @sohail

Comment: please check my updated logcat. That is the runtime error i get when i use all three answers provided for this question

Comment: @sohail ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on MainActivity.java's line 75. what's that line?

Comment: final String col = cols[j];

Comment: It works but it doesn't display two coloumns in a row. i wanted it in this format. Anyways, got the answer. Thank you.thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Ok. As per requirement, your code is incorrect. You will need to run loop for once only here (as many rows you require), and inside that you will need to create two textview dynamically. One for name, One for Surname. Add both of them to same table row. And you are done. [Reference](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/) @sohail

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
 TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
```

and add it inside

```
   for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {        
        final String col = cols[j];    

        columsView[k] = new TextView(this);  
        columsView[k].setText(String.format("%7s", col));   
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);  
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                         
        tableRow.addView(columsView[k]);
        k++;
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
```

Comment: please check my updated logcat. That is the runtime error i get when i use all three answers provided for this question

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` Point out line number 75.

Comment: final String col = cols[j];

Comment: What is `cols`? Print that array and say here

Comment: final String row=name+";"+surname;
        final String[] cols = row.split(";");